# Calculating $I=\int_{-1}^1{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}P_n(x)} \, dx$ where $P_n$ is a Legendre Polynomial.

Tags: integration, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

Calculating
$$I=\int_{-1}^1{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}P_n(x)} \, dx$$
Where $P_n$ is a Legendre Polynomial.

**My progress:** For any integral of the form:
$$\int_{-1}^1{f(x)P_n(x)} \, dx$$
Usinng Rodrigues formula, and integrating by parts $n$-times like in [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610468/calculating-i-int-111xmnp-nxdx-where-p-n-is-a-legendre-poly), we can assure that:
$$\int_{-1}^1{f(x)P_n(x)} \, dx=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n n!}  \int_{-1}^1 \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \big(f(x)\big)\cdot (x^2-1)^n $$

So, in this case: $f(x)=(1-x)^{-1/2}$

$$ I=\int_{-1}^1{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}P_n(x)} \, dx
= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n n!} \int_{-1}^1\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \big( (1-x)^{-1/2} \big) \cdot (x^2-1)^n  \, dx$$

Where:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \big( (1-x)^{-1/2} \big)=(-1)^n (1-x)^{-1/2-n}(1/2-n)_n$$
Using Pochhammer symbols.

So:

$$I=\frac{(1/2-n)_n}{2^n n!} \int_{-1}^1 (1-x)^{-1/2-n}\cdot (x^2-1)^n  \, dx$$

And here is where i have problems, sometimes, Betta function araises, but i can´t see how.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sqrt{2}\sum_{k\geq0}P_k(x)$. Now use the orthogonality of the L
egendre polynomials!

Comment: tired's good hint makes the problem very easy to solve. Depending on how you define $P_k$ you should probably prove it. If you use the generating function definition then it's trivial otherwise $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}} = \sum_{k\geq 0}P_k(x)t^k$ can be shown from the recursion formula: multiply the rec. formula by $t^{n+1}$ and sum over $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Then recognize one side as the derivative of the other to get a simple ODE for the function $\sum_{k\geq 0}P_k(x)t^k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments by tired the problem is easy once you establish 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} = \sqrt{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)\tag{1}$$
With this in hand the ortogonality relation $\int_{-1}^1 P_m(x)P_n(x){\rm dx} = \frac{2\delta_{nm}}{2m+1}$ does the rest of the job
$$\color{red}{\int_{-1}^1\frac{P_m(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}{\rm d}x = \sqrt{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{-1}^1P_n(x)P_m(x){\rm d}x = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2m+1}}$$
Below I will give a derivation of $(1)$ in case you haven't see it before.

---

$P_k(x)$ turns out to be the coefficient of $t^k$ in the generating function
$$G(x,t) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x) t^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}$$
and by taking $t=1$ we recover $(1)$.

If you don't know the generating function this can be derived either from [Legendre's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), from [Rodrigues' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_formula) using the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) or from the [recursion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Recursive_definition) 
$$(n+1)P_{n+1}(x) = (2n+1)xP_n(x) - nP_{n-1}(x)$$
I will here give a derivation based on this latter definition.

Multiply the recursion formula by $t^{n+1}$ and sum over $n=1,2,3\ldots$ to get
$$\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty nP_n(x)t^{n-1}\right](1-2xt+t^2) = (x-t)\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n\right]$$
We recognize the left hand side as the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n\right] \equiv \frac{dG(x,t)}{dt}$ giving us the ODE 
$$\frac{dG(x,t)}{dt} = \frac{(x-t)}{1-2xt+t^2}G(x,t) \implies G(x,t) = e^{\int_0^t\frac{x-t'}{1-2xt'+t'^2}{\rm d}t'} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}$$
where I used the substitution $u =1-2xt'+t'^2 \implies {\rm d}u = -2(x-t'){\rm d}t'$ to evaluate the integral.

Comment: I'm glad that u made such a nice answer out of my hint. A big (+1)!